# A diver makes 2.5 revs on the way from a 10-m-high platform to the water. Assuming zero init. vert. vel., find the avg ang. vel. during a dive

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

Free-fall kinematics gives 1.43 sec until the diver hits the water.  $\omega$ is easily found from 2.5 rev/1.43 sec = 1.75 rev/s = 11 rad/sec.  My question results from the following: Kinematics also gives -14 m/s = v just before the diver hits the water.  Equating this value (the magnitude) for the linear velocity of the diver in the negative y direction to the tangential velocity of the rotating diver into the equation $\omega = v_t/r$ gives (14 m/s)/0.6367 m = 22 rad/sec.  Then, $\bar\omega$ = (0 + 22)/2 = 11 rad/sec.  (The radius came from $r = s/\theta$ = 10 m/15.707 rad, where we let the arclength (*s*) be the length of the dive.)  Thus, my question: Why does this give the same answer?  If we imagine a really long dive of 100 m, this approach implies an ever-increasing $\omega$.  That violates conservation of angular momentum.  The diver will not spin faster and faster as he falls. No torque works on him.  $\omega$ won't change. *r* doesn't change. [Note: For the second solution to work, we assume that the moment of inertia is constant.  Let me re-write the question: A rigid disk completes 2.5 rotations during a 10 m drop at constant angular velocity.  Now, there are no concerns over the diver staying tucked or extending his body.  Ignoring friction, $\omega$ is now rigorously constant.]

Further, the instantaneous $\omega$ equals $\bar\omega$ at all times during the rotation because no acceleration occurs via the application of a torque or acceleration.  Also, the number of rotations that the diver completes every 10 m decreases because gravity accelerates the diver.  He traverses 10 m segments at an ever-increasing rate, allowing less time for rotations in each 10 m segment.  Lastly, this second 'solution' is related to problems of rotating tires, but, when tires rotate on a moving car, they DO rotate faster as the car accelerates. The diver here does NOT rotate faster as he falls.  Thus, setting the arclength equal to the distance of the fall is confounding me.  I am rather experienced at this subject, and I am distraught at having to post this question.  Perhaps, I am missing something obvious.

Comment: The diver can adjust their angular velocity without changing their angular momentum, by adjusting their body position to increase or decrease their moment of inertia. They pull their arms and legs closer to their torso to increase $\omega$, extend them out to decrease $\omega$.

Comment: But more importantly, why do you think that the linear velocity of the diver when they hit the water must equal the tangential velocity (of which part of their body) relative to their c.o.m. at the same instant?

Comment: @ThePhoton I fully understand moment of inertia, etc..  This is a freshman textbook problem, which does not state that the moment of inertia changes.  We assume it does not. As for your 2nd Q, I do not think that the linear velocity must equal the tang. velocity.  That's the entire point of my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Equating this value (the magnitude) for the linear velocity of the diver in the negative y direction to the tangential velocity of the rotating diver into the equation...Why does this give the same answer?

There's no reason, it's just a coincidence. Obviously if the diver did 5 revolutions from the same height, or 1 revolution, you wouldn't have found the same correspondence between the tangential velocity and the linear velocity.

> The radius came from r=s/θ = 10 m/15.707 rad, where we let the arclength (s) be the length of the dive.

The radius of the diver should be based on measuring the dimensions of the diver, not anything to do with the length of the dive. Probably (but I haven't worked it out in detail) your choice to use this figure is what caused the coincidence of the velocities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to believe that the diver's rotational inertia is constant, so the angular acceleration does not have to be zero.  This is why the problem asks for average angular velocity rather than final angular velocity.  Most divers do in fact change their body shape to control angular velocity throughout the dive.

Vertical transverse motion of the body's center of mass is changed by external net force on the body.  If the only force is gravity (that is, ignoring air resistance), then vertical acceleration is constant.  This allows approximate calculation of time in the air.  Time in the air may vary slightly depending on body orientation, but we can interpret the distance to be within perhaps 30cm of 10 meters.  Time in the air is fairly easy to calculate.

The definition of average angular velocity is total amount of rotation divided by time.  This has nothing to do with instantaneous rotational values during the fall.  Rotational inertia, angular velocity, and angular acceleration can vary.  Only angular momentum must remain constant.

In the explanation provided in your question, the formula $\bar\omega=\frac{0+\omega}{2}$ is incorrect.  This assumes a constant non-zero angular acceleration.